# Why are Integer.parseInt(String s, 2) and Integer.toBinaryString(int i) incompatible?

Tags: java

Why are this two methods using two different approaches while processing binary numbers? String which represents negative binary number in `Integer.parseInt(String s, 2)` method should start with `-` character, but `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)` returns string with additional 1 ahead. So, this code

```
Integer.parseInt(Integer.toBinaryString(-1), 2);
```

throws `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. What is the reason of such behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design; [`Integer.toBinaryString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29)

> Returns a string representation of the integer argument as an **unsigned integer in base 2**.

(emphasis added).

I.e., `toBinaryString` provides a way to format an integer as the common [two's complement representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which is the way most processors actually store signed integers internally.

Comment: It's clear, but why Integer.parseInt() couldn't parse integer argument as an unsigned integer in base 2? It is really annoying and I think that there are some reason for this restriction. I looked through Integer class source, but I didn't find there any reason to forbid such input

Comment: @zvzdhk If you really want only the absolute part of your integer to be converted to binary, call `Math::abs` before using it.

Comment: @zvzdhk Because `parseInt` uses a different convention to handle signs, which is the convention that [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) uses. If you use that method, you can read your integers back in with `parseInt`.

Comment: @larsmans, thank you. Do you have any idea how could I overcome it? What if I want to parse string representation of negative binary number? Of course, I don't want to change strings manually.

Comment: @zvzdhk: to be honest, I can't find such a method in the `Integer` class, and I'm a bit surprised by that. I think you should go through `Long.parseLong` and a check whether the number you get is larger than 2**31-1.

Comment: @larsmans, thank you for honesty :) if nobody suggests better idea in few days I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

`Integer::parseInt(String,int)` is expecting a string and so it is looking for the `-` symbol in negative number. Whereas the `Integer::toBinaryString(int)` is for giving you the binary equivalent of your input. In Binary, negative numbers are represented by 2's Compliment.